# Installing as root vs installing with sudo

Tags: software-installation, sudo, root

Is there a difference in outcome or application behaviour by installing packages with

```
sudo -i
apt install something
```

versus

```
sudo apt install something
```

Comment: It is the same thing as long as you do not use "I/O redirection".

Comment: If that is the case, would you mind posting an answer stating so?

Comment: Read `man sudo`.

Comment: hey waltinator, thanks for the valuable contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a difference in outcome or application behaviour by installing packages with

No, but that is not what "sudo" is about.

1 of the key features of "sudo" is the ability to track and trace *directly* who issued the command. Where "sudo" logs it as the user that issued it. Doing it from "root" will log it as "root.

Not an issue for a single admin system but a serious problem when there is more than one admin on a system and a command was issued that was not supposed to be issued.

Comment: If auditing is your concern, there are ways of tying together commands run under a root shell spawned from `sudo -i` back to the originating user: https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking solely about using the `apt` command, the two invocations are identical.  Other commands that may depend on environment variables and such could potentially act differently.